# Pasting an image from Gboard to a PWA on Android

Tags: android, image, google-chrome, clipboard, gboard

Has anyone found a way to paste an image from Gboard to a PWA (Progressive Web App) in Google Chrome on Android? I have tried using `<input type="text">` and `<span contenteditable>paste image here</span>`.

On MS Windows (10) both these two types of input fields can be used to paste a copied image from the clipboard (and capture an image Blob). But maybe not on Android (13).

Comment: you got solution for that?

Comment: @Heena Sorry, no. The handling of images on clipboard on Android is still a mess. (Android 13)